# How can I modify the Win10 registry, to offer a program call in the context menu, depending on a certain file type?

Tags: windows-10, contextmenu, regedit

I have a question about Windows10 registry. We all know the context menu which opens when you rightclick a file. In the following example we see how I can use an entry in the registry to offer a program call by right-clicking on any file. 
[image shows the win10 regEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Msz.jpg)

My question is, how can I limit the call to a specific file type? For example if I do the same with a *.png file it doesn't work. 
[image shows the win10 regEdit with another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Vdj.jpg)

I would be grateful for ideas and hints where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.
With the following entry it seems to work for me:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.specificFileType\shell\MyName\command
```